# Past Simple for long actions

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Should I say,

> My son was coughing yesterday night

or

> My son coughed yesterday night?

Past Progressive usually describes long actions that happened at a spesific time in the past, but still here it's also about a long action that happened in the past.

I would be thankful to anyone who would answer.

Comment: Those two sentences mean vastly different things. If your son *coughed*, then he coughed once. If he *was coughing*, then he was coughing off-and-on that night.

Comment: You may use "coughed" instead of "was coughing" in this context if you specify the duration: "My son coughed _all_ yesterday night."

Comment: Now it's clearer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> My son coughed yesterday night

Would mean that he coughed once and that was all.

> My son was coughing yesterday night

Is a longer action and ould mean that he was coughing for a length of time, not just once

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first answer...

> My son coughed yesterday night

^ sounds like a one-time thing. While the meaning could be the same, it would be a very strange way to describe a prolonged period of coughing.